# Get first occurrence value in each column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my df.
I want to get the first value in each column which contains `(F)`

```py
>>> d = {0: ['1', '2(F)', '6', '8', '5'], 
    1: ['8(F)', '6', '8', '4(F)', '4'], 
    2: ['1', '6', '8(F)', '4(F)', '5'],
    3: ['1', '8', '8', '1', '5']}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> df
      0     1     2  3
0     1  8(F)     1  1
1  2(F)     6     6  8
2     6     8  8(F)  8
3     8  4(F)  4(F)  1
4     5     4     5  5
```

And the result should look like this

```py
0    2(F)
1    8(F)
2    8(F)
3     NaN
```

But when I used the code below, I received some errors

```
>>> mask = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('F'))
>>> a = mask.idxmax().where(mask.any())
>>> print(df[a])

KeyError: '[nan] not in index'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way

```
mask = df.applymap(lambda x: '(F)' in x)

df[mask].bfill().iloc[0,]
Out[624]: 
0    2(F)
1    8(F)
2    8(F)
3     NaN
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4):

Use numpy indexing for get values by `idxmax` and last add `where`:

```
mask = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('F', na=False))
a = mask.idxmax()   
s = pd.Series(df.values[a, a.index]).where(mask.any())
print(s)
0    2(F)
1    8(F)
2    8(F)
3     NaN
dtype: object
```

Another solution with reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), filtering and get first value by [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html), last add non exist values by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
s = df.stack()
s = s[s.str.contains('F', na=False)].groupby(level=1).first().reindex(df.columns)
print (s)
0    2(F)
1    8(F)
2    8(F)
3     NaN
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4):

#### `applymap`, `lookup`

```
mask = df.applymap(lambda x: '(F)' in x)
vals = df[mask].lookup(mask.idxmax(), df.columns)
pd.Series(vals, df.columns)

0    2(F)
1    8(F)
2    8(F)
3     NaN
dtype: object
```

---

#### Numpy Variant

Over engineered

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import find

v = df.values.astype(str)
m = find(v, '(F)') >= 0
i = m.argmax(0)
j = np.arange(v.shape[1])

pd.Series(np.where(m[i, j], v[i, j], np.nan), df.columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's, a one-liner but it doesn't give out answer for 4th row:

`df.replace("\d$", np.nan, regex=True).dropna(how='all', axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.dropna().iloc[0], 0)`

It clears all elements other than \F, then for each column it finds out first non-empty elements.